# Looking for Help Understanding sed commands in os.system() Python lines

Tags: python, sed, os.system

I am working on translating some code I have written into a parallel process to be distributed on a computer cluster at my home university. In order to prepare to write my script for the cluster, I began by reading one of the sample snippets of Python code provided by the cluster:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

# This script replicates a given test with varied parameters
# creating unique submit scripts and executing the submission to the CRC SGE queue

# Imports
import os
import shutil
import string

basedir=os.getcwd()
origTestFol='wwd'
templFol='template'
origTestDir= basedir + '/' + origTestFol
templFolDir= basedir + '/' + templFol

steps=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
primes=[2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31]
trials=[6,7,8,9,10]

for step in steps:
    newTestDir= origTestDir + '_nm_' + str(step)
    if not os.path.exists(newTestDir):
        os.mkdir(newTestDir)
    os.chdir(newTestDir)
    for trial in trials:
       newTestSubDir= newTestDir + '/' + str(trial)
       if not os.path.exists(newTestSubDir):
            shutil.copytree(templFolDir,newTestSubDir)
            os.chdir(newTestSubDir)   
            os.system('sed -i \'s/seedvalue/' + str(primes[trial]) + '/g\' wwd.nm.conf')
            os.system('sed -i \'s/stepval/' + str(step) + '/g\' qsubScript.sh')
            os.system('qsub qsubScript.sh')
            os.chdir(basedir)
```

I can follow the code up to the last four lines [e.g. up to "os.system('sed -i ...)"] but then have a hard time following the code. Is there any chance others could help me understand what these last four lines are doing. Is there a way to describe the lies in pseudocode? So far as I can tell, the first sed line attempts to replace "seedvalue" with the value of primes[trial], but I'm not sure what the seedvalue is. I'm also not sure how to understand the "stepval" in the subsequent line. Any light others can shed on these questions will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a little search on sed: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed#In-place_editing

In short: `sed -i 's/old/new/g' file` replaces all the occurrence of `old` with `new` in `file`. The `-i` flag tells it do it in-line, modifying the file itself.

In your code, `seedvalue` and `stepval` are nothing but two words in the text files `wwd.nm.conf` and `qsubScript.sh`. Those commands are replacing those words just as you'd do in your text editor or word processor.

Comment: Thank you for the concise definition of the s/ command and the -i flag, @emnoor. This simple explanation helped me to grasp the function of the last four lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

`seedvalue` is a string, so its value is itself, same with `stepval`.

The first `sed` line will replace all the `seedvalue` strings in `wwd.nm.conf` (on all lines, that's what `/g` does, it stands for "global") with the value `str(primes[trial])`. Think about it like this:

Wherever the text `stepvalue` is found in the file `wwd.nm.conf`, put the value `str(primes[trial])` (whatever that evaluates to in Python).

The second `sed` call will do something similar but with `stepval` and the result of `step` and it will replace text in the file `qsubScript.sh`.

Comment: Many thanks, @Phillip! I was sure that seedvalue and stepval were strings, but was confused because the code doesn't define those strings. I'm just now grasping that the code leaves those as undefined variables such that users can replace "seedvalue" with some line of code they wish to change in their "wwd.nm.conf" script. The point of the script above, if I understand it correctly, is to slightly modify a single script and its associated .job file and then submit the new job file (with qsub) to run the modified script. Thank you for helping me to grasp this.